# Resource server returns error "invalid token"

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I use keycloak as authorization server . 
[keycloak configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8I0U.png)

My application.yml for Resource server -> [application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx94W.png)

ResourceServer Code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Demo1Application {

@GetMapping("/test")
public String demo1(){

    return "Test";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
  } 

}
```

Problem is that , when I send request as **curl -H "Authorization: $Token" http://localhost:8085/test** I get an error - Invalid access token . I don't figure out what is wrong .

Comment: How are you generating the token?

Comment: I send request via postman to generate token 
grant_type : client_credentials
access_token_uri : localhost:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
client_id : securitytest
client_secret : 046ab0e1-ebea-4ac9-bd4b-42f086b9323d

Answer (score 1):

Not using Authorization: <type> <credentials> ?
Maybe try:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" http://localhost:8085/test
```